# how to create custom render helper that accepts dynamic context

Tags: ember.js

I wanted to know if its possible to create your own helper that works like render helper but can accept dynamic context name. For eg, if you were to look in http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/, you would see something like:

```
{{render "author" author}}
```

instead of it, I want to pass in dynamic context like

```
{{myRender someContextName someModel}}
```

where, someContextName is a property in the controller.

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4777